# Drupal published content not displaying in designated node

Tags: drupal, view

I have published content at `/news/content-title-here` and it is available when the direct link is followed however it does not show up on the **News** section of the page which as near as I can tell should be showing this content and does from other publishers.

I have checked multiple blogs and articles of similar things but can't seem to figure out what's happening.

I have tried publishing from an existing publisher account as well from my Admin account, neither works.

Comment: is the page handled by a view? Drupal has a billion different ways to handle pages, so this question is a bit vague as is

Comment: Yes. Home » Administration » Structure » Views
Filter Criteria > Content Type: News, Events

Just removed events, they vanished. News remains hidden regardless.

Comment: right, so if you compare the criteria for the view against the post does it all add up? It's pretty hard to debug this kind of thing blindly, so I can't tell you what to look for. I would first check to see if it requires taxonomy term relation or something

Comment: It does, I've made new content via the menu and the existing published links are available under the /news/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new View and started from scratch to see where things went wrong.

Turns out my News View had a criteria that was messing things up.

```
Filter Criteria > Content: Date - start date (field_event_date)
```

Removed that and voila - everything showed up.